# Changing a <div> text in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I have a `<div>` list with text in it for each `<div>`. This list is made by an `*ngFor` and I can get the index of each `<div>`.

What I want to do is that when I click on the `<div>` for `restaurant.name`, the text becomes an `<input type="text">` I write something to replace and then when I click elsewhere the text is updated. I can't figure how to change it back after.

Here's my code :

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let restaurant of event.restaurants; let index = index">
   <div class="col-xs-5" (click)="update=true">
       <input *ngIf="update" type="text" name="champ" value="{{restaurant.name}}" placeholder="{{restaurant.name}}"/>
       <span *ngIf="!update">{{restaurant.name}}</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-5">
       {{restaurant.category.description}}
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-2">
       <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="DelRestaurant(index)">{{'EVENT_RESTAURANT_REMOVE' | translate}}</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now how can I set a default value for `update` ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Where is your typescript code? If this works in JavaScript it should also work in TypeScript.

Comment: I got nothing in my typescript code for that problem. Because I don't know how to write it, the changing of the tag, the focus etc...

Comment: Take a look at `ngIf`, based on your click you can set a property to show the `input` tag.

Comment: I added a ng-init and it's an improvement

Comment: But it didn't work because Angular2 doesn't have `ng-init`...

Comment: It works now ! Anybody knows how to disappear the input then ?

Comment: well, reverse the ngIf on some action, hehe :)